# How to fix this python code about Boolean variables and if statements

Tags: python, if-statement, boolean

The question:

> Clunker Motors Inc. is recalling all vehicles in its Extravagant line from model years 1999-2002 as well all vehicles in its Guzzler line from model years 2004-2007. Given variables modelYear and modelName write a statement that assigns True to recalled if the values of modelYear and modelName match the recall details and assigns False otherwise.

The code :

```
if 1999 <= modelYear <= 2002 and modelName == "Extravangant":
    recalled = True
elif 2004 <= modelYear <= 2007 and modelName == "Guzzler":
    recalled = True
else:
    recalled = False
```

Can't figure out what is missing after checking other people's code.

Comment: What's the problem here?  You're saying your code doesn't work?  What doesn't work about it?  Are you getting the wrong value of `recalled` in the end?  What do you see if you try to `print(modelYear)` and `print(modelName)`?

Comment: You could combine the `if` and `elif` statements into a single `if` statement using `or`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Extravangant` is misspelled. It should be `Extravagant`. Perhaps that's the issue.

Comment: Such a simple mistake that I've overlooked, thanks! Works now.

Comment: @KumoraV If this answer helped you, please accept it.